# Twitter-bootstrap carousel - ease in out AND fade background color on slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I seem to be able to get it to slide or fade colors but not both.  Trying to make it slide in from the right and transition between different background colors.

Jsfiddle:
jsfiddle.net/HEzuM/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this with some fiddling. Can see my solution here: jsfiddle.net/HEzuM/4/